# ASP.NET SiteMap Display All Nodes

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I have a .sitemap file that contains all of my nodes that I want to display for my side navigation. I am having trouble displaying all of my nodes when I get to the sub level. Everything just disappears when I visit the sub-page. In otherwords, when I am in the homepage.aspx page, all of my nodes are visible. When I enter the level1a.aspx page, all of the nodes disappear. I have no code behind. Is there a setting to display all nodes? Or would I need to write code to display them all?

Here are files:
web.config

```
    <siteMap>
        <providers>
    <add name="SiteMap" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="~/my.sitemap" />
        </providers>
    </siteMap>
```

control.ascx

```
<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" SiteMapProvider="SiteMap" runat="server" />
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1"></asp:Menu>
```

my.sitemap

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
<siteMapNode url="/HomePage.aspx" title="Home Page"  description="">
  <siteMapNode url="/level1.aspx" title="Level 1"  description="">
    <siteMapNode url="/level1a.aspx" title="Level 1 A"  description="" />
    <siteMapNode url="/level1b.aspx" title="Level 1 B"  description="" />
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made the experiment and it works fine...

Double check all your pages contain a reference to your user control

This is what I did

UC

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyMenuUC.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.MyMenuUC" %>
<asp:SiteMapDataSource runat="server" ID="mySiteMapDataSource" ShowStartingNode="false" />
<asp:Menu runat="server" DataSourceID="mySiteMapDataSource"></asp:Menu>
```

Web.sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
    <siteMapNode url="~/Default.aspx" title="Home"  description="">
        <siteMapNode url="~/MenuWithUC1.aspx" title="page 1"  description="" />
        <siteMapNode url="~/MenuWithUC2.aspx" title="page 2"  description="" />
    </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

MenuWithUC1.aspx

```
    <%@ Register Src="~/MyMenuUC.ascx" TagName="SharedMenu" TagPrefix="menu" %>
    ....
    <menu:SharedMenu runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="post me" runat="server" />
```

MenuWithUC2.aspx

```
    <%@ Register Src="~/MyMenuUC.ascx" TagName="SharedMenu" TagPrefix="menu" %>
    ....
    <menu:SharedMenu runat="server" />
    <asp:Button Text="post me" runat="server" />
```

The buttons on each page are just to test that the `Menu` control keeps its state on each post

Comment: Hmm weird. I place the the control on the masterpage and it only works for the HomePage.aspx, but not for the sub-page. Which is suppose to inherit the controls from the master page. I place another control within the sub-page and it appears. Any way to display the side nav with only the control placed within the MasterPage?

Comment: Ah! I found out why it wasn't working! Silly mistake. I had the control within a <asp:Content></asp:Content> of my MasterPage and my sub-page <asp:Content></asp:Content> overwrote the sitemap control. Thanks for the help though =D

Answer (score 0):

try with EnableViewState = true

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" EnableViewState="true"></asp:Menu>
```